# Plot non time series data in grafana

Tags: cassandra, grafana

I installed the Cassandra source data for Grafana with the help of this link https://github.com/HadesArchitect/GrafanaCassandraDatasource/wiki/Quick-Demo.
The data that I have in Cassandra is not a time series data. Is there any way to plot some charts without a timestamp column?

Comment: Unless a bar chart is good enough for you, that's not currently possible: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/7158

Answer (score 0):

Bar chart panel is designed for non timeseries (categorical data): https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/bar-chart/